# No code signing identities found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I try to create a new Xcode project named Twitter Searches I get the following error. However if I use a different name I am able to build the project with no errors. What does this mean?

No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found

Answer (score 2):

You have to log into developer.apple.com and register an app identifier and create a Certificate for it, then create and download a Development provisioning profile. The bundle identifier of the app has to match between your Developer account and Xcode.

Comment: Do you need to be a paid member to do so?

Comment: You do. Apple locks it down pretty tight for people who do not have an active Developer account.

Comment: I just signed up for an Apple account, paid my 99 + tax.
I have no idea what a bundle identifier is or how I might use it.
Any clues?

Comment: The following answer (below) is an example of a useful answer that provides context and information.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to run on real device(iPhone,iPad),you need  certificate and provisioning profile,if you don't have them  you can run on simulator. to get these certificate and provision profile you have to buy member ship program from https://developer.apple.com

to know more about this follow the link [How to enrol IOS developer account](http://iosdevelopmenttutorials.com/how-to-enroll-in-the-ios-developer-program/)

Edit :

Now with the new xcode 7 we can run our app on our device freely without any certificates and provisioning profiles.